# How do I truncate a java integer to fit/exand to a given number of bytes?

Tags: java, byte, int, archive

I am designing an archive format(Just for fun) in Java using this template-

```
First 4 bytes: Number of files in the archive
Next 4 bytes: Number of bytes in the filename
Next N bytes: Filename
Next 10 bytes: Number of bytes in the file
Next N bytes: File contents
```

from [PHP Safe way to download mutliple files and save them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372764/php-safe-way-to-download-mutliple-files-and-save-them).

I am having on trouble with finding the values of the number of files etc. but I don't know how to expand an integer into 4 bytes.

Is it similar to this- [How do I truncate a java string to fit in a given number of bytes, once UTF-8 encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119328/how-do-i-truncate-a-java-string-to-fit-in-a-given-number-of-bytes-once-utf-8-enc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an `int` into 4 bytes like this:

```
public byte[] getBytesForInt(int value) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    bytes[0] = (byte) ((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
    bytes[1] = (byte) ((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
    bytes[2] = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
    bytes[3] = (byte) (value & 0xFF);
    return bytes;
}
```

This would put them in big-endian order as often used for transport (see [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). Alternatively if you're already dealing with an [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) you could wrap it with a [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and just use [`writeInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29). For example as per your template:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("foo.dat");
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);
dataOut.writeInt(numFiles);
dataOut.writeInt(numBytesInName);
dataOut.writeUTF(filename);
dataOut.writeLong(numBytesInFile);
dataOut.write(fileBytes);
```

Note that the [`writeLong()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeLong%28long%29) is actually 8 bytes. I'm not sure why you'd want to use 10 and I imagine 8 from a `long` is plenty.

Comment: In your code I think there is an error on line 2. Unexpected int keyword?

Comment: I understand that a byte is 8 bits and an integer in java is 32 bits. So does that mean I don't even need to go through all of this and just write the integer since an integer is 4 bytes(32 bits)

Comment: @Liam: yes, a Java `int` holds 4 bytes worth of data, so writing it directly will have the same effect. **However** a normal `OutputStream` has no method to directly write an `int` (don't be fooled with [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)), read its documentation to see why). Therefore you need some other way to write it: Either convert it to `byte[]` and write that or get a class that can write `int` values).

Comment: Yeah, `writeInt()` should do what you need. No need to convert to bytes manually. I provided the byte example since your question asked for it :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`DataOutput`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html)/[`DataInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) implementation to write/read that format, it does most of the work for you. The classical implementations are [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and [`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/DataInputStream.html):

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
dos.writeInt(numFiles);
// for each file name
byte[] fn = fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"); // or whichever encoding you chose
dos.writeInt(fn.length);
dos.write(fn);
// ...
```

Reading works pretty much the same.

Note that these use [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). You'll have to check (or specify) if your format uses big- or little-endian.

Comment: Another option would be to use `ByteBuffer`. It's not as easy to use, but it's good if you want to do multiple passes over some sections of data without copying.

Comment: @Daniel: that's true. [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) also has the advantage of having [configurable byte order/endianness](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder)).